# Questions on $f: (X,\tau)\to(Y,\sigma)$

Tags: general-topology

Let $\tau =${$\emptyset$,{1,2},{1,2,3},$X$} be a topology on $X =${1,2,3,4,5}

Let $\sigma =${$\emptyset$,{a},{a,b},$Y$} be a topology on $Y =${a,b,c,d}

We want to show whether: $f$ is continuous, $f$ is open, $f$ is closed, and/or $f$ is a homeomorphism.

**Work:**

**Homeomorphism:** Showing that It Is not a homeomorphism seems easy enough since It won't be one to one.

**Continuous:** I didn't know If I needed to use a delta epsilon proof to show continuity or If there was an easier way to go about that. I'm not strong at delta / epsilon proofs. (I'm working on it, it's just slow moving. If anyone has any good recommendations for where to go to help with this it'd be appreciated.)

**Open / Closed:**
I know that in a topology the intersection and union of closed/open sets is closed/open. I also know that the empty set and the whole set are open.

Thanks for any ideas.

[image]

Comment: What is the mapping $f$???

Comment: I wrote down everything that we were given on the problem. Should I take out the word mapping from my questions title?

Comment: You can't show anything about $f$, if $f$ is not even defined.

Comment: This cannot possibly have been all you were given. If you want to test whether $f$ is continuous, etc., you need to be told what $f$ is.

Comment: although as a heads up, I think there might be some fundamental misunderstanding of $\epsilon$-$\delta$ proofs for you. There is no reason why you could possibly need that here. If a set is open, its preimage must be open. I.e: if $f(A) \in \sigma$ (for $A \subseteq X$), it better be the case that $A \in \tau$.

Comment: There is a picture of what we were given. It was the only one on the paper that didn't make any sense

Comment: This question makes $\epsilon$ sense

Comment: @Fmonkey2001: the question you've taken a picture of makes no sense because $f$ is not specified, but perhaps $f$ is specified somewhere else on the page. If not, the instructor made a blunder.

Comment: That explains some of my confusion then. Maybe i'm not as topology dumb as I originally thought. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Actually, on second thought, the question might be *trying* to ask whether it is *possible* for a function between these spaces to be continuous, etc. It is not possible for these spaces to be homeomorphic, for example, because they don't even have the same cardinality.

Comment: Ahhh, i see! If that's the case then I was correct in my logic of the homeomorphism part

Answer (score 0):

There are no $\delta-\epsilon$ proofs in general topology besides in metric spaces. The definition of a continuous function between topological spaces if:

> The function $f:X\to Y$ is continuous if for every open set $U\subset Y$, $f^{-1}(U)$ is open in $X$.

If you are working with a metric space, this turns out to be equivalent to the $\delta-\epsilon$ definition. What this means is that if you look at any open set $U$ in $Y$, and then look at all the elements of $X$ which map to $U$  under $f$. This set is called $f^{-1}(U)$. If $f^{-1}(U)$ is open for all open sets $U$, then $f$ is continuous. Since you are not given a function $f$ to work with, we cannot tell whether or not it is continuous.

You have given some information about open and closed sets, but this is asking about an open or closed function.

> A function $f:X\to Y$ is open if for every open set $U\subset X$, $f(U)$ is open in $Y$.

and

> A function $f:X\to Y$ is closed if for every closed set $C\subset X$, $f(C)$ is closed in $Y$.

Note that a function can be continuous without being open or closed, and functions can be open without being closed, and vice-versa. You have to check each one separately.

Sounds like you understand why the function cannot be a homeomorphism.